Managing Data Encapsulation in PySpark Streaming with Event Hubs
When streaming data using PySpark, the primary message I receive is encapsulated within a key named "body."
spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()

Is there a way to avoid this and directly get the data as it is?
I'm attempting to flatten the body, but the incoming data lacks a consistent structure, making it challenging to process.

are you using azure databricks

Yes it’s Azure databrick

As you mentioned when using streaming data using PySpark, You are getting encapsulated within a key named "body."
The data within the body attribute is stored in binary format.
To extract its elements. I have tried the below approach.
below is the example:
map_df = decoded_df.selectExpr("from_json(json, 'MAP<STRING, STRING>') AS parsed_map")
flattened_df = map_df.select(explode(col("parsed_map")).alias("key", "value"))
nested_fields = flattened_df.filter(col("value").startswith("{"))
flattened_fields = flattened_df.filter(~col("value").startswith("{"))
nested_parsed_df = nested_fields.select(
    col("key"),
    from_json(col("value"), "MAP<STRING, STRING>").alias("nested_value")
)

In the above code parsing JSON dynamically as a MAP  using the from_json function with a schema of type MAP<STRING, STRING> to handle dynamic key-value pairs.
Exploding the MAP to flatten key-value pairs into rows
Separating known nested fields for additional flattening
Results for flattened_df & nested_parsed_df:
+---------+-------------------------------+
|key      |value                          |
+---------+-------------------------------+
|name     |CityA                          |
|dt       |1234567890                     |
|details  |{"temp":22.5,"pressure":1013}  |
|coord    |{"lon":12.34,"lat":56.78}      |
|location |CityB                          |
|timestamp|9876543210                     |
|info     |{"humidity":65,"pressure":1020}|
|position |{"x":98.76,"y":54.32}          |
+---------+-------------------------------+

+--------+----------------------------------+
|key     |nested_value                      |
+--------+----------------------------------+
|details |{temp -> 22.5, pressure -> 1013}  |
|coord   |{lon -> 12.34, lat -> 56.78}      |
|info    |{humidity -> 65, pressure -> 1020}|
|position|{x -> 98.76, y -> 54.32}          |
+--------+----------------------------------+



Thank you for your response. However, as I mentioned earlier, the data structure is not fixed; it keeps changing and is often in a nested JSON format. Therefore, it's not possible to define a specific structure in this case.

Hi sujeet i have updated the solution can you please check and let me know if you have any questions?

Can you please check if the solution helped you?
